# wordpress login(set_current_user) makes error

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I try to login an user in to wordpress/woocommerce with this code:

```
function login_user_in_wp ($user_id) {
    $user = set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, $remember);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login);
}
```

It "works" and logs the user in.  The problem is, that the page is making an error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wc_maybe_store_user_agent(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 1551

Does anybody know why? I have newest version.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

```
function login_user_in_wp ($user_id) {
    $user = set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, $remember);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, 10, 2);
}
```